# Horizontal iScroll can't scroll vertical?

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll

I've downloaded iScroll and I am using the horizontal scroll. Works great except that if the content and the "horizontal scrolldiv" is longer than the device screen, you can't scroll down to see the content below the horizontal scroll.
How can i solve that?

Downloaded from: http://cubiq.org/iscroll  Using code in: examples/horizontal-scroll

Comment: Did you set both hScrollbar and vScrollbar to true?

Comment: Yup! You can see an example here: http://www.bristolhotel.com/pizzeria/mobil/pizza.php but off course you won't see the problem on the computer.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, got the same problem?

Comment: @HaggleLad did you ever got the answer? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Yep just added an answer

Answer (score 3):

I had to customize iScroll.js to make this work.  Here's the changes I made

(Please note these line numbers refer to iScroll v4.1.9)

---

line 100: `onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { e.preventDefault(); },`

change to: `onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { /* e.preventDefault(); */ },`

---

line 106: `onTouchEnd: null,`

change to: `onTouchEnd: function (e) { e.preventDefault(); },`

---

line 390: `timestamp = e.timeStamp || Date.now();`

insert below: `if( Math.sqrt( deltaX*deltaX ) > 5 ) { e.preventDefault(); }`

---

In addition to this to get the scroll bar to appear where I wanted I had to make the following change:

line 218: `else bar.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;z-index:100;' + (dir == 'h' ? 'height:7px;bottom:1px;left:2px;right:' + (that.vScrollbar ? '7' : '2') + 'px' : 'width:7px;bottom:' + (that.hScrollbar ? '7' : '2') + 'px;top:2px;right:1px');`

change to: `else bar.style.cssText = 'position:relative;z-index:100;' + (dir == 'h' ? 'height:7px;bottom:7px;left:2px;right:' + (that.vScrollbar ? '7' : '2') + 'px' : 'width:7px;bottom:' + (that.hScrollbar ? '7' : '2') + 'px;top:2px;right:1px');`

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iScroll 4, this can be fixed by setting `onScrollStart` to null when initializing.

Example:

```
var scroller = new iScroll('wrapper', { onBeforeScrollStart: null });
```

Comment: this worked for a few horizontal swipes. try swiping horizontally for about 10 times (on iPhone) = it becomes laggy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution (from http://gist.github.com/hotmeteor/2231984):

```
var point, pointStartX, pointStartY, deltaX, deltaY;
var scroller = new iScroll('scrollerId', {
    vScroll: false,
    vScrollbar: false,
    hScrollbar: false,
    snap: 'li',
    momentum: false,
    onBeforeScrollStart: function(e) {
        point = e.touches[0];
        pointStartX = point.pageX;
        pointStartY = point.pageY;
        null;
    },
    onBeforeScrollMove: function(e) {
        deltaX = Math.abs(point.pageX - pointStartX);
        deltaY = Math.abs(point.pageY - pointStartY);
        if (deltaX >= deltaY) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            null;
        }
    }
});
```

Sadly, you can't lean on iScroll's internal `absDistX` and `absDistY`, because (for whatever reason), they are updated too late.